# Как транслировать изображение с экрана на фронтальную камеру?

Tags: android, камера

Мне нужно перенаправлять на канал камеры другое изображение для того чтобы приложение думало что смотрит фронтальной камерой на человека а это было фото или видео воспроизводящееся на экране.

Как сделать трансляцию экрана на фронтальную камеру?

Я искал подобные приложения на Google Play, но не нашел ничего подобного.

Comment: "приложение думало что смотрит" - звучит как просто использование какого-то videoView где будет картинку показывать, зачем вам тогда камера вообще?

Comment: Похоже он имеет ввиду чтоб стороннее приложение думало что обращается к камере.